# Gelfand Transform in a specific case

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-algebras

What is the gelfand transform of an operator in the algebra generated by a bounded normal operator and it's adjoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebra is commutative, and isomorphic to $C(X)$ where $X$ is the maximal ideal space. Under the Gelfand Transform, the operator itself goes to the function $f(z)=z$.

Have a look at continuos functional calculus in your book- they should prove this statement over there.